# How to use find_or_create in create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use find_or_create method in my game dates controller. I don't know how to use that method in create action, when params are in game_date_params. Any suggestion how can I extract date from game_date_params?

```
class GameDatesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :authenticate_admin

  def index
    @game_dates = GameDate.all
    @showcases  = Showcase.joins(:game_dates)
  end

  def new
    @game_date = GameDate.new
    @game_date.referee_stats.build
  end

  def create
    @game_date = GameDate.new(game_date_params)
    if @game_date.save
      redirect_to showcases_path
      flash[:success] = "Game date created"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @game_date = GameDate.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @game_date = GameDate.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to root_url
    flash[:success] = "Game date deleted"
  end


  private

  def game_date_params
    params.require(:game_date).permit(:date, referee_stats_attributes: [ :games_count, :showcase_id ])
  end
```

This is output from POST action:

> Started POST "/game_dates" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-01 10:21:44 +0200
>   Processing by GameDatesController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"jmuOmMCO/WTFIkxrsw5l2cPVMqZAl7h11f281I+OyoHH3ddwKoB9ANAqvQEHulR88c7fzQXnnIaxs8FChMCjqw==",
>   "game_date"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2016", "date(2i)"=>"4", "date(3i)"=>"1",
>   "referee_stats_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"games_count"=>"4",
>   "showcase_id"=>"1"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Game date"}   User Load
>   (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER
>   BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]   GameDate Load (0.4ms) 
>   SELECT  "game_dates".* FROM "game_dates" WHERE "game_dates"."date" IS
>   NULL LIMIT 1    (0.2ms)  BEGIN   SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "game_dates"
>   ("date", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING
>   "id"  [["date", "2016-04-01"], ["created_at", "2016-04-01
>   08:21:44.864669"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-01 08:21:44.864669"]]   SQL
>   (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "referee_stats" ("games_count", "showcase_id",
>   "game_date_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4,
>   $5) RETURNING "id"  [["games_count", 4], ["showcase_id", 1],
>   ["game_date_id", 7], ["created_at", "2016-04-01 08:21:44.866897"],
>   ["updated_at", "2016-04-01 08:21:44.866897"]]    (18.1ms)  COMMIT
>   Redirected to http://localhost:3000/showcases Completed 302 Found in
>   31ms (ActiveRecord: 20.1ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GameDate.find_or_create_by(game_date_params)` would find record with **ALL** `game_date_params`, so you could do this by finding with specific params like `date` and assign rest of attributes to it via block. for example:

```
def create
  # find or initialize the record
  @game_date = GameDate.find_or_initalize_by(date: game_date_params[:date]) do |game_date|
    # Accept nested attributes as well
    game_date.assign_attributes(game_date_params)
  end

  if @game_date.save
    redirect_to showcases_path
    flash[:success] = "Game date created"
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

See also: [find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) and [AttributesAssignment](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html) API docs

Comment: That works, but not quite as I thought. It creates new game date, even when game date with chosen date is in database.

Comment: Really?! It should act like `@game_date = GameDate.find_by(date: game_date_params[:date]) || GameDate.new(date: @game_date_params[:date])`. Maybe there's something wrong with your date format. Could you print game_date_params[:date] and use it find manually, see what's happening.

Comment: I added output from POST action to my question, for better readability. Surprisingly, even when I changed code in create action to that from your comment, game dates with same date are saving. Attributes from debug console: raw_attributes:
  date: 2016-04-01
  id: '8'
  created_at: &1 2016-04-01 08:50:37.664718353 Z
  updated_at: *1

Answer (score 1):

It should be like :

```
def create
    @game_date = GameDate.find_or_create_by(game_date_params)
    if @game_date.present?
      redirect_to showcases_path
      flash[:success] = "Game date created"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
 end
```

Comment: I've tried this, and this is output from console: "undefined method `find_or_create' for #<Class:0x007f8e83018718>"

Comment: Another error: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column game_dates.date(1i) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "game_dates".* FROM "game_dates" WHERE "game_dates".... ^ : SELECT "game_dates".* FROM "game_dates" WHERE "game_dates"."date(1i)" = '2016' AND "game_dates"."date(2i)" = '3' AND "game_dates"."date(3i)" = '31' AND "referee_stats_attributes"."0" = '--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters games_count: ''2'' showcase_id: ''1'' ' LIMIT 1

Comment: Actually it is finding records with all params present in `game_date_params` and i guess `date(1i)` is a dynamic attribute. Try to check for those params which you want to be unique in whole table like : `User.create_with(game_date_params).find_or_create_by(email: game_date_params[:email], anyattr: game_date_params[:someparam])`

Answer (score 0):

Create action is for creating an object after the new action has been called and update action if the same but for edit. Mixing create & update logic i not a good idea. Maybe you should rethink what are you trying to do in your views.